# NDSolve with embedded FindRoot and NIntegrate

Tags: equation-solving, numerical-integration

I am trying to plot results for a very simple differential equation of the form:

$$\frac{\partial^2 x(N,z'(N))}{\partial N^2} = F(N,z'(N)), $$

where $z'(N)$ is a function of $N$ that needs to be solved using FindRoot for at every $N$ position, and $F(N,z')$ is a nasty equation that results from a numerical integration over:

$$ F(N,z') = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp\left( -\frac{x'^2}{2\sigma_{x'}^2} \right) F(N,z',x')dx'$$.

So, I put together some mathematica code but it runs terrible slow (on the order of a day or two)! I noticed there were some things that affected the speed of the code particularly the numerical coefficient in front of $F(N,z'(N))$. But I was wondering if there is any help to be given to get better/faster results! Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Note: I had to use $NN$ in place of $N$ in my equations because its a function in mathematica. Also, in the FN function I have to actually copy and paste the output of FNzprime (an ugly mess) in the integrand for it to evaluated.

```
(*constants*)
e = -1.60217733*10^-19;
m = 9.109389699999999*10^-31;
epsilon = 8.854187817620391*10^-12;

(*basic equations*)
rs2 = {zprime, xprime + K/(gamma*kw) Sin[kw*zprime], 0};
ro2 = {(NN + 10000)*lw, x + K/(gamma*kw) Sin[kw*(NN + 10000)*lw], 0};

betas = {beta - K^2/(4 gamma^2) Cos[2 kw*zprime],K/gamma Cos[kw*zprime], 0};
betao = {beta - K^2/(4 gamma^2) Cos[2 kw*(NN + 10000)*lw],K/gamma Cos[kw*(NN + 10000)*lw], 0};

betaDot = {(c*K^2*kw)/(2 gamma^2)Sin[2 kw*zprime], -((c*K*kw)/gamma) Sin[kw*zprime], 0};

deltar2 = ro2 - rs2;
Rgam2 = Sqrt[deltar2[[1]]^2 + deltar2[[2]]^2];
Ec2 = (e/(4 Pi*epsilon)) (deltar2/Rgam2 - betas)/(gamma^2 Rgam2^2 (1 - (deltar2/Rgam2).betas)^3);
Erad2 = (e/(4 Pi*epsilon)) Cross[deltar2/Rgam2, Cross[deltar2/Rgam2 - betas, betaDot]]/(c*Rgam2*(1 - (deltar2/Rgam2).betas)^3);

Bc2 = Cross[deltar2/Rgam2, Ec2];
Brad2 = Cross[deltar2/Rgam2, Erad2];

Fbc2 = Cross[betao, Bc2];
Fbrad2 = Cross[betao, Brad2];


sumEtran = (Ec2[[2]] + Erad2[[2]]);
sumFBtran = Fbc2[[2]] + Fbrad2[[2]];



(*Numeric Functions*)

ZPRIME[NN_?NumericQ, x_?NumericQ, xprime_?NumericQ, gamma_, K_, kw_, beta_, sigma_, lw_] :=zprime /. FindRoot[sigma == (1/(gamma kw))Sqrt[gamma^2 + K^2] (EllipticE[kw*(NN + 10000)*lw, K^2/(gamma^2 + K^2)] - EllipticE[kw zprime, K^2/(gamma^2 + K^2)]) - beta \[Sqrt](((NN + 10000)*lw - zprime)^2 + (x - xprime + (K Sin[kw *(NN + 10000)*lw])/(gamma kw) - (K Sin[kw zprime])/(gamma kw))^2), {zprime, 0}]


coeff = ((e*lw^2)/(gamma*m*beta^2*c^2) (10^-10/e)/(2 Pi (30*10^-6) (10^-5)) Exp[-(sigma^2/(2 (10^-5)^2))]);
FNzprime =coeff (sumEtran + sumFBtran) /. {lw -> 0.026, K -> 1, beta -> Sqrt[1 - 1/(4000/0.511)^2], gamma -> 4000/0.511, c -> 3*10^8, kw -> (2 Pi)/0.026, zprime -> ZPRIME}

FN[NN_?NumericQ, x_?NumericQ, sigma_?NumericQ] :=With[{ZPRIME = ZPRIME[NN, x, 0, 4000/0.511, 1, (2 Pi)/0.026, Sqrt[1 - 1/(4000/0.511)^2], sigma, 0.026]}, 
  NIntegrate[ (Exp[-(xprime^2/(2 (30*10^-6)^2))]) FNzprime, {xprime, -300*10^-6, 300*10^-6}]]

sol00 = NDSolve[{X''[NN] - (FN[NN, 0, 10^-8]) == 0, X[0] == 0, X'[0] == 0}, X, {NN, 0, 140}]

Plot[X[NN] /. {sol00}, {NN, 0, 10}, Evaluated -> True]
```

Comment: It could be better you show your function `FN` without this code.

Comment: @AlexTrounev Yes, I tried to do so, but the function is pretty big and ugly! It would have been a mess and perhaps less clear.

Comment: What do you get after day or two of waiting?

Comment: @AlexTrounev I get similar results, very nice approximation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can decrease evaluation time to few minutes by filtering function `FN` as follows:

```
(*constants*)e = -1.60217733*10^-19;
m = 9.109389699999999*10^-31;
epsilon = 8.854187817620391*10^-12; lw = 0.026; kk = 1; beta = 
 Sqrt[1 - 1/(4000/0.511)^2]; gamma = 4000/0.511; c = 
 3*10^8; kw = (2 Pi)/0.026; sigma = 
 10^(-8); coeff = ((e*lw^2)/(gamma*m*beta^2*c^2))*
      (1/(10^10*e)/((2*Pi*(30/10^6))/10^5))*
      Exp[-(sigma^2/(2*(10^(-5))^2))]; 

(*basic equations*)

rs2 = {zp, xp + kk/(gamma*kw) Sin[kw*zp], 0};
ro2 = {(nn + 10000)*lw, x + kk/(gamma*kw) Sin[kw*(nn + 10000)*lw], 0};

betas = {beta - kk^2/(4 gamma^2) Cos[2 kw*zp], kk/gamma Cos[kw*zp], 0};
betao = {beta - kk^2/(4 gamma^2) Cos[2 kw*(nn + 10000)*lw], 
   kk/gamma Cos[kw*(nn + 10000)*lw], 0};

betaDot = {(c*kk^2*kw)/(2 gamma^2) Sin[
     2 kw*zp], -((c*kk*kw)/gamma) Sin[kw*zp], 0};

deltar2 = ro2 - rs2;
Rgam2 = Sqrt[deltar2[[1]]^2 + deltar2[[2]]^2];
Ec2 = (e/(4 Pi*epsilon)) (deltar2/Rgam2 - 
      betas)/(gamma^2 Rgam2^2 (1 - (deltar2/Rgam2).betas)^3);
Erad2 = (e/(4 Pi*epsilon)) Cross[deltar2/Rgam2, 
     Cross[deltar2/Rgam2 - betas, betaDot]]/(c*
      Rgam2*(1 - (deltar2/Rgam2).betas)^3);

Bc2 = Cross[deltar2/Rgam2, Ec2];
Brad2 = Cross[deltar2/Rgam2, Erad2];
Fbc2 = Cross[betao, Bc2];
Fbrad2 = Cross[betao, Brad2];
sumEtran = (Ec2[[2]] + Erad2[[2]]);
sumFBtran = Fbc2[[2]] + Fbrad2[[2]];
ZPRIME[nn_?NumericQ, x_?NumericQ] := 
    zp /. FindRoot[sigma == (1/(gamma*kw))*Sqrt[gamma^2 + kk^2]*
              (EllipticE[kw*(nn + 10000)*lw, kk^2/(gamma^2 + kk^2)] - 
                 EllipticE[kw*zp, kk^2/(gamma^2 + kk^2)]) - 
            beta*Sqrt[((nn + 10000)*lw - zp)^2 + 
                  (x + (kk*Sin[kw*(nn + 10000)*lw])/(gamma*kw) - 
                       (kk*Sin[kw*zp])/(gamma*kw))^2], {zp, 0}];

FNz = coeff*(sumEtran + sumFBtran) /. 
     {zp -> ZPRIME[nn, x-xp]};
```

Now instead of

```
FN[n_?NumericQ] :=   
     NIntegrate[
   Exp[-(xp^2/(2*(30/10^6)^2))]*
    Evaluate[FNz /. {x -> 0, xp -> xp, nn -> n}], 
       {xp, -300/10^6, 300/10^6}];
```

we use filtered function `fp` based on list interpolation. First we recognize that function `fp` is periodic with a period of 1

```
lst1 = Table[{n, 
   NIntegrate[
     Exp[-(xp^2/(2*(30/10^6)^2))]*
      Evaluate[FNz /. {x -> 0, xp -> xp, nn -> n}], 
         {xp, -300/10^6, 300/10^6}, PrecisionGoal -> 5] // Quiet}, {n, 0, 1,.005}];
lst2 = Table[{n, 
       NIntegrate[
         Exp[-(xp^2/(2*(30/10^6)^2))]*
          Evaluate[FNz /. {x -> 0, xp -> xp, nn -> n}], 
             {xp, -300/10^6, 300/10^6}, PrecisionGoal -> 5] // Quiet}, {n, 1,3,.02}];
        ListPlot[{lst1,lst2}]
```

[image: Figure 1]
So we can make periodic interpolation as follows

```
fp = Interpolation[Join[lst1, {{1, lst1[[1, 2]]}}], 
  PeriodicInterpolation -> True]
```

With this function we integrate equation as

```
sol00 = NDSolve[{X''[n] - fp[n] == 0, 
       X[0] == 0, X'[0] == 0}, X, {n, 0, 140}]

Plot[X[nn] /. {sol00}, {nn, 0, 140},Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"N", "X"}]
```

[image: Figure 2]

Finally we can test how periodic interpolation is good for this problem. We calculate 160 points in the beginning and 60 random points in the end of interval `{NN,0,160}`, and compare points with `fp`. We can check that only 3 points from 220 not follow to `fp`. Therefore it  is good approximation.
[image: Figure 3]

Comment: Jugging from OPs question I reckon that `ZPRIME` depends on `xprime` (the integration variable in F) maybe OP can comment on this issue with this running example at hand. Further I would strongly recommend circumventing the intermediate symbolic expressions by introducing numeric functions. One should also check that the computed integrals are accurate (enough) a `PrecisionGoal -> 5` and `Quiet` might kill features and possibly critical error messages. What this solution boils down to with the current parameters is X(N)=(c N^2)/2, where c is the average of F(N) over the computational domain.

Comment: Rerunning the code with more gird points (e.g. `lst =Table[{n,...}, {n, 0, 140,1/2}];`) for the interpolation completely changes the result, since F is highly oscillatory. OP should check the given expressions and parameters and I would recommend getting F under control before attempting a solution of the ODE.If the displayed behavior of F is correct I would recommend trying to find a good value for its average (c) over the computational domain and approximate it as constant and use the analytical solution X(N)=(c N^2)/2 in this approximation.

Comment: @N0va Yes, ZPRIME is a function of xprime. I am checking the code/example right now. The xprime or "xp" as you have used Alex is missing from the ZPRIME[nn_?NumericQ, x_?NumericQ] function. Check my ZPRIME function in my original post.

Comment: @user1886681 No, `xp` is not missing, since `ZPRIME` depends on `x-xp`.  We then can put `FNz = coeff*(sumEtran + sumFBtran) /. 
     {zp -> ZPRIME[nn, x-xp]};`. And so on.

Comment: @N0va I have calculated `FN` with `zp -> ZPRIME[nn, x-xp]` and result for `X`. You are right that it is not stable. Probably we should accumulate `FN` with different set of points.

Comment: @N0va See update to my answer with periodic interpolation.

Comment: @AlexTrounev I have a small variation of this problem (includes another integration over "sigma" instead of it being a constant "1e-8") that I've been using to try and speed up calculation times but with little success. Would you have any ideas?

Comment: @user1886681 Thank you! What is interval for `sigma` and how we can integrated over?

Comment: @AlexTrounev Check my new post (https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/233468/nested-nintegrate-with-findroot). Essentially its the same problem with sigma in ZPRIME replaced with (s-s') and a integration over s'. A change to the coeff and no longer needing to use NDSolve