# Nested NIntegrate with FindRoot

Tags: equation-solving, numerical-integration

I am trying to numerically integrate a function using nested NIntegrate:

$$F(N,x,s)=\int_{-\infty}^s \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} K(N,z',x,x') g_{x',s'} dx'ds' $$

where the kernel of the integration, $K(N,z'x,x')$, is a messy expression defined in the mathematica code below, and $g_{x',s'}$ is a bi-variate gaussian defined by:

$$ g_{x,s'}=\frac{n}{2\pi\sigma_{x'}\sigma_{s'}}\exp\left({ -\frac{x'^2}{2\sigma_{x'}^2} }\right)\exp\left({ -\frac{s'^2}{2\sigma_{s'}^2} }\right).$$

The tricky part(s) is that:

1. $z'$ in the $K(N,z',x,x')$ needs to be solved for numerically using FindRoot and will have a $s'$ dependence.
2. The integration upper limit over $ds'$ is a variable $s$.
3. I suspect the kernel is oscillatory with $N$ (denoted "Kernel" in the code below) so maybe an averaging of the kernel over $N$ can be done to simplify the kernel and eliminate $N$ if the integrations prove to be too time consuming.

At the end, I would like a function, F(N,x,s), that would be able to plot across $s$ for a given $(N,x)$ values i.e. Plot[F[a,b,s,{s,-1e-5,1e-5}].

```
(*Constants*)
e = -1.60217733*10^-19;
m = 9.109389699999999*10^-31;
epsilon = 8.854187817620391*10^-12;
re = 2.81794092*10^-15;
c = 2.99792458*10^8;
n = -10^-10/e;
KK = 1;
lw = 0.026;
kw = (2 Pi)/lw;
gamma = 4000/0.511;
beta = Sqrt[1 - 1/gamma^2];
sigmaS = 10^-5;
sigmaX = 30*10^-6;
coeff = n/(2 Pi*sigmaS*sigmaX) Exp[-(xprime^2/(2 sigmaX^2))]*
Exp[-(sprime^2/(2 sigmaS^2))];

(*Preliminary Equations*)
rs2 = {zprime, xprime + KK/(gamma*kw) Sin[kw*zprime], 0};
ro2 = {(NN + 10000)*lw, x + KK/(gamma*kw) Sin[kw*(NN + 10000)*lw], 0};

betas = {beta - KK^2/(2 gamma^2) Cos[kw*zprime]^2,KK/gamma Sin[kw*zprime], 0};
betao = {beta - KK^2/(2 gamma^2) Cos[kw*(NN + 10000)*lw]^2,KK/gamma Sin[kw*(NN + 10000)*lw], 0};

betaDot = {(c*KK^2*kw)/(2 gamma^2)Sin[2 kw*zprime], -((KK*c*kw)/gamma) Sin[kw*zprime], 0};

deltar2 = ro2 - rs2;
Rgam2 = Sqrt[deltar2[[1]]^2 + deltar2[[2]]^2];

Ec2 = (e/(4 Pi*epsilon)) (deltar2/Rgam2 - betas)/(gamma^2 Rgam2^2 (1 - (deltar2/Rgam2).betas)^3);
Erad2 = (e/(4 Pi*epsilon)) Cross[deltar2/Rgam2,Cross[deltar2/Rgam2 - betas, betaDot]]/(c*Rgam2*(1 - (deltar2/Rgam2).betas)^3);

sumElong = (Ec2[[1]] + Erad2[[1]]);
sumEtran = (Ec2[[2]] + Erad2[[2]]);

(*Numerical Functions*)

ZPRIME[NN_?NumericQ, x_?NumericQ, xprime_?NumericQ, s_?NumericQ, sprime_?NumericQ] := zprime /.FindRoot[s - sprime == (Sqrt[gamma^2 + KK^2] (EllipticE[kw*(NN + 10000)*lw,KK^2/(gamma^2 + KK^2)] - EllipticE[kw zprime, KK^2/(gamma^2 + KK^2)]))/(gamma kw) -beta Sqrt[((NN + 10000)*lw - zprime)^2 + (x - xprime + (KK Sin[kw *(NN + 10000)*lw])/(gamma kw) - (KK Sin[kw zprime])/(gamma kw))^2], {zprime, 0}]


Kernel = coeff re/gamma (sumElong*betao[[1]] + sumEtran*betao[[2]])/.{zprime -> ZPRIME[NN, x, xprime, s, sprime]};

FNxprimesprime[NN_?NumericQ, x_?NumericQ, xprime_?NumericQ, s_?NumericQ, sprime_?NumericQ]:= Kernel

FNsprime[NN_?NumericQ, x_?NumericQ, s_?NumericQ, sprime_?NumericQ] :=NIntegrate[FNxprimesprime[NN, x, xprime, s, sprime], {xprime, -300/10^6, 300/10^6}]

FN[NN_?NumericQ,x_?NumericQ, s_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[FNsprime[NN,x, s, sprime], {sprime,-10^-4, s}]

lst1 = Table[{ss, FN[0,0, ss], PrecisionGoal -> 5] // Quiet}, {ss, -10^-5, 10^-5, 10^-6}]
ListPlot[lst1]
```

Answer (score 1):

This case is not so different from what we discussed [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/232987/ndsolve-with-embedded-findroot-and-nintegrate/233236?noredirect=1#comment590142_233236). We have used same approach and get answer

```
(*Constants*)e = -1.60217733*10^-19;
m = 9.109389699999999*10^-31;
epsilon = 8.854187817620391*10^-12;
re = 2.81794092*10^-15;
c = 2.99792458*10^8;
n = -10^-10/e;
KK = 1;
lw = 0.026;
kw = (2 Pi)/lw;
gamma = 4000/0.511;
beta = Sqrt[1 - 1/gamma^2];
sigmaS = 10^-5;
sigmaX = 30*10^-6;
coeff = n/(2 Pi*sigmaS*sigmaX) Exp[-(xprime^2/(2 sigmaX^2))]*
   Exp[-(sprime^2/(2 sigmaS^2))];

(*Preliminary Equations*)
rs2 = {zprime, xprime + KK/(gamma*kw) Sin[kw*zprime], 0};
ro2 = {(NN + 10000)*lw, x + KK/(gamma*kw) Sin[kw*(NN + 10000)*lw], 0};

betas = {beta - KK^2/(2 gamma^2) Cos[kw*zprime]^2, 
   KK/gamma Sin[kw*zprime], 0};
betao = {beta - KK^2/(2 gamma^2) Cos[kw*(NN + 10000)*lw]^2, 
   KK/gamma Sin[kw*(NN + 10000)*lw], 0};

betaDot = {(c*KK^2*kw)/(2 gamma^2) Sin[
     2 kw*zprime], -((KK*c*kw)/gamma) Sin[kw*zprime], 0};

deltar2 = ro2 - rs2;
Rgam2 = Sqrt[deltar2[[1]]^2 + deltar2[[2]]^2];

Ec2 = (e/(4 Pi*epsilon)) (deltar2/Rgam2 - 
      betas)/(gamma^2 Rgam2^2 (1 - (deltar2/Rgam2).betas)^3);
Erad2 = (e/(4 Pi*epsilon)) Cross[deltar2/Rgam2, 
     Cross[deltar2/Rgam2 - betas, betaDot]]/(c*
      Rgam2*(1 - (deltar2/Rgam2).betas)^3);

sumElong = (Ec2[[1]] + Erad2[[1]]);
sumEtran = (Ec2[[2]] + Erad2[[2]]);

(*Numerical Functions*)

ZPRIME[NN_?NumericQ, x_?NumericQ, xprime_?NumericQ, s_?NumericQ, 
  sprime_?NumericQ] := 
 zprime /. 
  FindRoot[s - 
     sprime == (Sqrt[
         gamma^2 + 
          KK^2] (EllipticE[kw*(NN + 10000)*lw, 
           KK^2/(gamma^2 + KK^2)] - 
          EllipticE[kw zprime, KK^2/(gamma^2 + KK^2)]))/(gamma kw) - 
     beta Sqrt[((NN + 10000)*lw - zprime)^2 + (x - 
           xprime + (KK Sin[kw*(NN + 10000)*lw])/(gamma kw) - (KK Sin[
               kw zprime])/(gamma kw))^2], {zprime, 0}]

kernel = coeff re/gamma (sumElong*betao[[1]] + sumEtran*betao[[2]]);
FN[nn_?NumericQ, x0_?NumericQ, ss_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[
   Evaluate[(kernel /. 
       zprime -> ZPRIME[NN, x, xprime, s, sprime]) /. {NN -> nn, 
      x -> x0, xprime -> xp, s -> ss, sprime -> sp}], {xp, -300/10^6, 
    300/10^6}, {sp, -10^-4, ss}, PrecisionGoal -> 6] // Quiet
```

Now we can calculate  and plot lists

```
lst1 = Table[{ss, FN[0., 0, ss]}, {ss, -10^-5, 10^-5, .5 10^-6}];
    lst2 = Table[{ss, FN[1., 0, ss]}, {ss, -10^-5, 10^-5, .5 10^-6}];
    ListLinePlot[{lst1, lst2}, PlotRange -> All,Frame -> True]
```

[image: Figure 1]